# Physical keyboard inputs wrong characters on Android Emulator

Tags: android, keyboard, emulation

I have been using the physical keyboard on the Android Emulator for a while, but now something is wrong and I get strange symbols when I press any character; it does not matter which keyboard (en/es/fr) is displayed on the screen. Does anyone know why this is happening?

Comment: If start a new emulator, everything comes back to normal for a while...

Answer (score 20, accepted):

Try using this `shift+alt+o`. This helped me solve the issue.

Comment: For me various combinations of SHIFT, CTRL, ALT and O worked.

Comment: tried on mac, option + shift + o, does not work. What's the mac version of this?

Comment: restarting the emulator fixes the problem for me

Answer (score 99):

For mac

1. Move your cursor to end.
2. Use Option + Shft + Left arrow key to select whole text.
3. Press backspace to delete it and it will automatically switch back to normal english characters.

Comment: This worked for me, but does anyone know how or why this works, or how or why this is even happening?

Comment: What the hell was that? :D Why it's event got that way?

Comment: Quite possiblly the most ridiculous thing i've seen in the past few weeks. Bravo!

Comment: I second that. The physical keyboard was typing hieroglyphs, the backspace wasn't working but now it is.

Comment: you dropped this ` `

Comment: thanks for the solution, is there a name to this bizarre phenomena? not sure if this was designed to support localization and other languages but strange indeed.

Comment: You're a real hero.

Comment: In 12+ years developing android I've never accidentally entered this condition.  Today was the day!  Thank for the info - I was in the system settings trying to reset the keyboard, etc.  Couldn't figure out how to exit this weird mode.

Answer (score 11):

Cold starting the emulator fixed things for me.

Comment: the above "shift+alt+o" can't work for me, but a cold start can back to normal!

Comment: Smacking my head that I didn't think to try this!

Answer (score 2):

At the end, I uninstalled and installed the emulator again, and now it works fine. I think that should be there another solution, but so far it's the only thing that keep the keyboard working normally.

Answer (score 1):

I was using the accepted answer but using a special shortcut every time was getting annoying. So I poked around a bit and found the permanent solution. Go to the settings on the android emulator keyboard. (You can long press the `,` character on the Gboard.) Once there, go to `Advanced` and disable `Emoji with the physical keyboard`. Cold boot and you should be good to go.

Answer (score 0):

Another solution would be to disable the soft keyboard from bottom down icon.